# Duplicate a window in all screens

Tags: c#, winforms

In a multi-monitor environment, how can I display a form on all the screens? Is it possible to get handles to the different screens available, and display a form in a different screen than where the main window lives?

What I really need to do is to clone a window on all displays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A multi-monitor system effectively has a single, very large display area.
There is nothing different about a point in a different monitor; it will just be far to the right of the previous monitor.

You can use the [`Screen` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) to find all of the user's screens.

You can loop through `Screen.AllScreens` and create a new instance of the form for each screen, setting it's location to a point within that screen's `WorkingArea`.