# C#: ListView does not add items that come from another Class

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Good day,

I'm new to whole programming thing and can't figure out / find a solution.
I've been trying to populate my ListView with Items that come from another Class.
But the ListView doesn't seem to do anything when the `Class2` returns an `Array`.

Here is how i make it :

1 ) I search for something and send the value to `Class2` ( Main Class in Form1 ):

```
private void tbSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Class2 cl2 = new Class2();

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearch.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Textbox is Empty.....");
            }
            else
            {
               listV.Items.Clear(); 
               cl2.Search(tbSearch.Text);  // Give a value to Method in Class2
            }
        }
    }
```

2 ) Then in `Class2` i do some internet search and return `arrays` with the Results :

```
public async void Search(string search_value)
    {
            /*** Read the XML Data that i've got from Response ****/

            foreach (XmlNode node in XMLlist)
            {
                /****** Get the values that i need and write them into an array *******/

                string[] result = new string[10];

                result[0] = series_title;
                result[1] = series_type;
                result[2] = series_episodes;
                result[3] = series_score;
                result[4] = series_id;
                result[5] = series_title_english;
                result[6] = series_status;
                result[7] = series_start_date;
                result[8] = series_end_date;
                result[9] = series_image;

                Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
                fm1.Update_SearchList(result); // Return an array to Form1
            }
    }
```

3) And at the end i try to populate the ListView with the returned `array` ( Form1 again ) :

```
public void Update_SearchList(string [] array)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(array);
        this.listV.BeginUpdate();                
        this.listV.Items.Add(item); // Here the Item.Add() Method doesn't add new Items to the ListView or they just aren't being shown.
        this.listV.EndUpdate();          
    }
```

The `listView.View` is set to `Details` and the columns are being generated on `Form.Load`.

Is there a problem with how i execute the `listView.Items.Add();` Method or is there another problem ?

When i try to do this whole operation in one single `private void tbSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)` everythings works.

Thank you for your time and have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a new instance of `Form1` in `Form1 fm1 = new Form1();`, which is not the instance of your caller.

I would suggest you return the result from `Search()` and process in `Form1`, or better, a callback function.

I haven't tried but a quick bypass solution could passing `Form1` as a reference to the `Search()` function, but TBH it looks nasty to me.

```
private void tbSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    //...
           cl2.Search(tbSearch.Text, ref this); // pass the ref of current instance to cl2
        }
    }
}

public async void Search(string search_value, ref Form1 frm) {
    //...
    foreach (XmlNode node in XMLlist) {
        // ...
        frm.Update_SearchList(result); // use the frm reference instead
    }
}

public void Update_SearchList(string [] array) {
    if (InvokeRequired)
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => Update_SearchList(array)));
    else {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(array);
        this.listV.BeginUpdate();                
        this.listV.Items.Add(item);
        this.listV.EndUpdate();  
    }        
}
```

**Note: code not tested, just a quick idea!!!**

Also, I don't think if your async will work as expected if called in a non-async function.

**Edit:**

You can also try to return results and proceed in main form. Find the draft code as follows, but it's synced and may block your UI thread. Again, code **untested**!

```
private void tbSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    //...
            var results = cl2.Search(tbSearch.Text);
            foreach (var item in results) Update_SearchList(item);
        }
    }
}

public List<xxx> Search(string search_value) {
    //...
    var results = new List<xxx>(); // change type to the correct type
    foreach (XmlNode node in XMLlist) {
        // ...
        results.Add(result);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking in to this matter. I have tried to do as u have suggested. Have changed the method to sync. But i get an error that says : `<this> can not be passed as a ref or out argument because the element is read-only.`

Comment: @idkWhatToDo No wonder :) It was just a quick thought. Maybe you can try my previous solution of using Events to pass variables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131608/duplicate-windows-in-all-screens-with-function

Comment: Your solution with Events is a bit hard to understand , but the second suggestion works. The items are being added to the List. I can live with small freezes when the function works. Now i have to figure out how to add them as i want but this is another story. Thank you for taking your time and helping me !

Comment: @idkWhatToDo You're most welcome! Well, if your search result is from internet, it may take unpredictable time to complete, and the freezed UI may annoy users. I would suggest you to look into `await` and `async`, and call async methods in retrieving XML data. It probably only a few lines of code or even add a few modifiers :)